# Which computational complexity is larger, $O(2^n)$ or $O((\log{n})^{\log{n}})$?

Tags: computational-complexity

Doing algorithm complexity analysis in my assignments, but don't know how to compare these two algorithm complexity,

$O(2^n)$ and $O((\log{n})^{\log{n}})$

Which one is larger and why?

Comment: Is it $(\log n^{\log n})$ or $\log (n)^{\log n}$?

Comment: @idk If the former, we could just write $\log^2 n$ instead, so maybe the latter.

Comment: @user477343 Then you can write it as $(\log n)\cdot (\log n)$

Comment: Well, clearly $\lim_{n\to \infty}2^n$ approaches $\infty$ "faster".

Comment: @user477343 Or, better yet, $\log(n)^2$, which cannot be accidentally confused with $\log(\log(n))$.  In any event, I'm not sure how to answer this question without clarification.  I am also confused about the title---both limit are infinite, so neither is larger.  Is the question about $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ vs $\mathcal{O}((\log(n)^{\log(n)})$?

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. Updated the second term.

Comment: @idk  (and the upvoters of your comment) $(\log n^{\log n})$ and $\log (n)^{\log n}$ is the same. It is $\log n^{\log n}.$ I think you wanted to ask if it is  $\log (n^{\log n})$ or  $(\log n)^{\log n}$

Comment: @user477343 $\log^2 n$ is usually (at least sometimes) used for $\log(\log n)).$ So it is more clear to write $(\log n)^2$

Comment: @miracle173 for problems like that, I have my own notation.

If we have $$\underbrace{\log_a^{ \ \ k}(\log_a^{ \
 \ k}(\log_a^{ \ \ k}\ldots\log_a^{ \ \ k}}_{b\text{ times}} \,n)\ldots),$$then this is the same as writing $\log_{(a, b)}^kn$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson for problems like that, I have my own notation.

If we have $$\underbrace{\log_a^{ \ \ k}(\log_a^{ \
 \ k}(\log_a^{ \ \ k}\ldots\log_a^{ \ \ k}}_{b\text{ times}} \,n)\ldots),$$then this is the same as writing $\log_{(a, b)}^kn$.

Comment: @user477343 Okay... so you have your own idiosyncratic notation.  I've never seen anyone else use that notation.  Rather than introduce a new notation that might be confusing (again, is the $k$ representing the $k$-th power of $\log(n)$?  Or is it the $k$-fold composition of the $\log$?), you are better off using standard notation, and doing so in a way that *clearly* indicates what you are doing when there is ambiguity (e.g. use more parentheses, explain the notation in the text).

Comment: @idk comment to my comment: $(\log n^{\log n})=\log n^{\log n}$, there is not otherway to interpret the parantheses. It is still unclear, what this means. If in  $\log (n)^{\log n}$  the parantheses re used in the same way as in the previous expression (an unnecessary construct that enclosses $n$) then it can be removed and we end with  $\log (n)^{\log n}=\log n^{\log n}$. But now I sess that it could be interpreted as part of the function symbol, and then $\log (n)^{\log n}= (\log (n))^{\log n}$ and the meaning of the expression is clear.I think the latter interpretation is the usual one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, exponents matter much more than bases, so $2^n \gt \log n^{\log n}$
 To be more careful $2^n=e^{n \log 2}, \log n^{\log n}=e^{\log n \log \log n}$ so you just need $n \log 2 \gt \log n \log \log n$